# Why does ALS start in middle age?

Tags: neuroscience, pathology, neurodegenerative-disorders

Amyotrophic lateral sclerosis (ALS) often starts at middle age, but I didn't find any suggestion why. Something seems to trigger the symptoms in middle age.

If I am not mistaken, the [**sporadic** ALS](http://alsn.mda.org/article/putting-labels-types-als) is not genetic, but there are [genetic variants](http://alsn.mda.org/article/putting-labels-types-als). So these genes are with the person all his life. But why do the disease symptoms often start only in middle age?

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**
The causes of ALS are not well known. Some familial types are associated with toxic proteins, susceptibility to toxins and defective protein metabolism. My personal 2-cents is that metabolic and toxicologic defects tend to cause cumulative tissue damage over time, perhaps explaining the delayed onset.

**Background**
Amyotrophic lateral sclerosis (ALS), is a progressive, fatal disease characterized by the gradual degeneration and death of motor neurons.

In **90 to 95 percent of all ALS cases, the disease is sporadic**, meaning that it appears apparently at random. Individuals have no family history of ALS, and their family members are not considered to be at increased risk for developing it.

About 5 to 10 percent of all ALS cases are inherited. About one-third of all familial cases result from a defect in a gene known as “chromosome 9 open reading frame 72,” or C9orf72. The **function of this gene is still unknown**. Another 20 percent of familial cases result from mutations in the gene that encodes the enzyme copper-zinc superoxide dismutase 1 (SOD1). In case of mutations in the SOD1 gene it is though that **mutant SOD1 protein is toxic**.

Other inherited forms are believed to change in the processing of RNA, that may lead to ALS-related motor neuron degeneration. Other gene mutations implicate **defects in protein recycling**. And still others point to possible defects in the structure and shape of motor neurons, as well as **increased susceptibility to environmental toxins**.

<sub>Source: [NIH - ALS Facts Sheet](http://www.ninds.nih.gov/disorders/amyotrophiclateralsclerosis/detail_ALS.htm)</sub>

Comment: Thank you, Alice. Also for editing my question. I read this source before. If we talk about familial ALS - it's looks more clear. Accumulation of toxic mutant protein, for example. Some sort of accumulating defects. But what about sporadic? ~90% of the ALS. And also - sometimes ALS starts in young people.

Comment: @VGranin - no worries, happy to help. The disease etiology of the sporadic cases are, as far as I understand and as stated in my answer, often unknown. Because they, seemingly, don't have a genetic background, it is probably very hard to pinpoint what is at fault in these folks. In other words - I don't know and as far as I can see, no one really does. That is, implicitly, what 'sporadic' means - random occurrence / cause unknown.

Comment: Yeh I know that I will not get some proved reason. But maybe there is some studies that have some good suggestions based on some evidence ...  Also about the genetics -  I think that in all cases there must be some genetic background. The environment could trigger it - but must be something wrong in the genes from the beginning. And in middle ages the body gets weaker - so thinks go wrong more easily. It's only my suggestion.